# How can I make one central message for my jquery validate custom function?

Tags: jquery, message, validation

I'm using the [jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) to validate my form. I need to validate that 1 field of a section is filled in. This is the code I used: 
http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/2009/04/15/jquery-validation-indicate-that-at-least-one-element-in-a-group-is-required/

So, I have a few form fields with a "required_group" class, and the following lines of code in my document.ready function:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('required_group', function(value, element){
        var $module = $(element).parents('div.panel');
        return $module.find('.required_group:filled').length;
    },
    "Please fill out at least one of these fields");

jQuery.validator.addClassRules('required_group', {'required_group':true});
```

This works the way it's supposed to. But - I find it a bit messy to have the "Please fill out at least one of these fields" message show up by every field in the group. I'd prefer to have one message at the top of the group. How can I accomplish this using the validate plugin? Is there any way to customize where I want the message to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *showErrors* option to define your own message displaying function. From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

> showErrors    Callback    Default: None, uses built-in message disply.
>
> A custom message display handler. Gets the map of errors as the first
>   argument and and array of errors as the second, called in the context
>   of the validator object. The arguments contain only those elements
>   currently validated, which can be a single element when doing
>   validation onblur/keyup. You can trigger (in addition to your own
>   messages) the default behaviour by calling this.defaultShowErrors().

Edit: here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6vr4/13/) that does more or less what you need.

Comment: Not sure if I get how this works... can you provide some example code for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Added jsfiddle example. This is just showing the basic principle, you'll need to tweak the code to display other error messages as usual.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put that together for me! However, this seems to me to be complicated... I have many other simple validation rules, etc that I want to behave normally. Is there any simpler way?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I don't really see the complexity here. Use a custom showErrors function as I suggested, use the custom error message for elements having the "required_group" class, and use the default behavior for all other elements. Check the defaultShowErrors function for the default behavior.